# How to test App Engine project on Windows system?

Tags: windows, unit-testing, google-app-engine, go

Standart way: `goapp test` — doesn't work.

Output:

```
D:\Projects\MyProject>goapp test
can't load package: package .: no buildable Go source files in D:\Projects\MyProject
```

Answer (score 1):

`goapp test` looks for `*_test.go` files in the current directory if you don't specify the packages as parameters.

So either:

- navigate to the package directory which you want to test and which contains the `XX_test.go` files then execute the `goapp test` command
- or stay in your project folder and pass the package folder as parameter like this:
  `goapp test ./my/package`

Read more about [Local Unit Testing for Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/localunittesting/).

Comment: It just not work. `goapp test` not search in current directory, because he search in `/path/to/sdk/go_appengine/gopath`. And if i use path to my package, he didn't find depended packages. Why not found? Cause he search not in current dir.